# gRPC partial resource update

Tags: rest, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am writing a gRPC service. Sometimes I have to update a resource partially.
Is there something similar to [HTTP PATCH partial update](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3206264/application-development/how-to-perform-partial-updates-to-rest-web-api-resources.html)?

I usually just add just another updateXxx method to proto. So I am wondering is there some best practice?

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from implementing a partial update capability over gRPC. You have to do the same implementation yourself over HTTP, as well.

Comment: @Flimzy His question is about a best practice similar to HTTP's PATCH. I personally don't know a best practice. RPC isn't that opinionated :p

Comment: Here are Google's guidelines: https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods#update nNote in particular the FieldMask field in the request.

Comment: @Peter it looks like transcoding https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding

Comment: @Seaskyways: I understand the question. The answer is that there is no defined answer, either for HTTP or gRPC. There's only a very loose framework, within which you can implement your own partial update functionality.

Comment: Also Google provide Field Mask for this purpose: 
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/field-mask

Comment: still doesn't understand how to apply field mask. I define `FieldMask update_mask` path. But it doesn't filter the request.

Comment: Here is one example to handle  partial update: https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/patterns/partial_update.html